# Getting an error while parsing event body to json in aws console

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using lambda with aws and a serverless framework. When I test this with serverless offline it works completely fine but when I deploy it I keep getting a message: internal server error and when I log in to aws console, the Error says

```
  "errorType": "SyntaxError",
  "errorMessage": "Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0",
  "trace": [
    "SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0",
    "    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)",
    "    at module.exports.createPost (/var/task/handlers/post.js:17:12)",
    "    at Runtime.handler (/var/task/serverless_sdk/index.js:9:89602)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
```

This is my handler

```
module.exports.createPost = async event => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const post = {
    id: uuid.v4(),
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
    userId: 1,
    title: data.title,
    body: data.body
  };
  const params = {
    TableName: postsTable,
    Item: post
  };
  db.putItem(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return response(err.statusCode, err);
    } else {
      return response(200, post);
    }
  });
};
```

I'm testing this with

```
{
  "title": "post title",
  "body": "post body"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess body is already a json so if you do `json.parse` again, it will throw this error. If you remove the `json.parse`, it should be ok.